# Moving textfield when keyboard appears is covering up top textfields in (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, visible

I was first having problems with textfields on the bottom of the screen because the keyboard would cover them. Now that I fixed that problem I have a new one. When I try to enter text in a textfield that is at the top of the screen, the screen rises and does not let me see what I'm typing.

I think what I would ideally like to do is change how much the keyboard pushes the screen up. Below is the code I used for the initial change.

I just started learning to develop two weeks ago so I'm still getting familiar with all the syntax and functions.

```
var kbHeight: CGFloat!

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            kbHeight = keyboardSize.height
            self.animateTextField(true)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.animateTextField(false)
}

func animateTextField(up: Bool) {
    var movement = (up ? -kbHeight : kbHeight)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
    })
}
```

Comment: Is there an issue with the code you have posted? How is it different to your expected results?

Comment: That's not the right way, you are moving a fixed kbHeight. Please read [Managing the Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html). Also in your current context you should also consider the `y` position of the selected text field

Comment: The code works just fine but if there is a textfield that is in top half of the screen, it will move up to the point where I can't see what I'm typing.

Comment: That's why I said you should consider `y` position of the selected text field, if it's in upper half don't move else move. but still that's not the right way. Please go through the link that I have posted earlier that the right way.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm reading it right now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a suggestion

Instead of setting View's frame. put the view inside a UIScrollView.
then inside your keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide methods adjust the scrollview frame accordingly.

and set the scrollview's content offset using the "scrollRectToVisible" inside the the textfield delegate method.

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  CGRect rectText = textField.frame;
  self.scrollVIew scrollRectToVisible:rectText animated:TRUE];
}
```